# Do any iOS Email Clients allow the folders to expand/collapse like Outlook?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email

I have a 12+ gb exchange account, with hundreds of files & sub files.

The iOS mail client doesn't allow the folders to collapse & expand, which makes searching for files a real PITA.

Are there any mail clients that have the expand/collapse feature?

Answer (score 2):

The best folder management app for email I have used is [eMailGanizer Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/emailganizer-pro-email-client/id405732706?mt=8).

> Folders
>
> Expand/Collapse style folder navigation
>
> Find folders by searching
>
> Add, move, rename, & delete folders
>
> Off-line operation for later synchronization
>
> Universal Inbox, Unread, & other 'Smart' folders
>
> Show all folders/labels for email

Answer (score 0):

I also need this facility and just purchased " Emailganizer Pro. " It does expand and collapse folders... Can not say how thankful I am to have found this app.  Just wish they did an iPad version, but at least I can now use email on my phone.